# getContext is not working while creating google API client

Tags: android

I'm working on google GeoFencing.
I'm using tabView in my project and i'm not able to use "this" keyword for context while creating google API client.
Application is getting crashed if I debug into my phone.
help me

This is my java code:

```
private Context mContext;// ive tried using like this,


mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext()) //ive also tried with getActivity();
        .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) getContext())
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getContext())
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) mContext,
    (GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getContext())
        .build();

mClient.connect();
mGeofencing = new Geofencing(mClient,getContext());
```

Comment: Can you please add more context to the code snippet? Where is this code written? In your Fragment or View?

Comment: @elmorabea  case has been resolved, thank you soo much btw.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using fragment

plese use `getActivity()` instead in `getContext()`

```
private Context mContext;


mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()) 
    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) getActivity())
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getActivity())
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
    .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) mContext, (GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getActivity())
    .build();

mClient.connect();
mGeofencing = new Geofencing(mClient,getActivity());
```

I hope this will help you...

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use getActivity() and implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener to your Fragment or activity.